# PULL a project from GitHub remote branch

Tags: xcode, git, github

after checkout to the desired branch:

```
git checkout feature/myBranch
```

I want to pull the project contained in this branch to my local repository, how can i do that please.

Comment: What's the relationship of the remote "feature" to your local repository? On which branch should the code end up?

Comment: the code should be committed to that branch. But firstly, i need to get the code on my local machine to make changes on it and then push it. So how can i pull the project?

Comment: After "git checkout" your working copy should be on a local copy of the desired branch, so I don't quite understand what you are aiming for. Could you expand the question to describe the setup in greater detail?

Comment: Thanx for your reply, so you mean that `git checkout feature/myBranch` is enough to copy its content automatically into my local repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load the content of a remote repository by adding it as a remote and calling `git fetch`. That is all what needs to be done. After that, you already have the changes in your local repository, it’s just that there is no local branch pointing to them (but a remote branch like `origin/branch`).

When you can checkout a branch, then you already have everything in your local repository.

Comment: Thanx for your reply, so just `git checkout feature/myBranch` will automatically copy the content into my local repository ?

Comment: Not exactly. If you can checkout the branch, then you already had all the content in your local repository *before* checking it out. But of course it will put the content in your working directory.

Comment: Ok, so it will obviously update my local repository content with the remote branch content, am i wrong?

Comment: It will retrieve all the contents from the remote repository when running `git fetch <remote>`, so do that first (to update everything), and you will be fine.

Comment: @Luca Here's a nice explanation: [Git Branching - Remote Branches](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html)